# Busted won't recognize certain functions

Tags: lua, lua-busted

I'm using the Busted framework to test my lua programs. I have newest busted version

`user ~ $ busted --version
2.0.rc12-0`

I ran this program (its called etl)

`goto statement
::statement::`


 `error loading module 'etl' from file './etl.lua':
    ./etl.lua:6: '=' expected near 'statement'`

edit: I'm pretty sure that busted is referencing lua 5.1 or 5.2, but I only have lua 5.3.3 on my system. So how do I get busted to recognize 5.3.3?

proof I only have lua 5.3.3 on my system

`me ~ $ luaver list
==>  Installed versions: 
==>  lua-5.3.3`

Update: I had some different versions of lua hidden in another folder that luaver didn't recognize. I deleted those and then busted gave me this every time I tried to run it: 
`/usr/local/bin/busted: 3: exec: /usr/bin/lua5.1: not found`

Then I went to to the busted file in /usr/local/bin/busted and it was like this

```
#!/bin/sh

exec '/usr/bin/lua5.1' -e 'package.path="/home/sam/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/sam/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;"..package.path; package.cpath="/home/sam/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;"..package.cpath' -e 'local k,l,_=pcall(require,"luarocks.loader") _=k and l.add_context("busted","2.0.rc12-1")' '/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/busted/2.0.rc12-1/bin/busted' "$@"
```

so i need to change all that shit to lua5.3. My lua 5.3 is in /usr/local/bin.
Do I just take that file and start cutting out the 5.1 stuff and replacing it with 5.3 stuff?

Comment: It seems you're using different Lua versions as REPL or for running tests. `goto` is new since 5.2, `table.move` exists since 5.3. So whatever you used to run the program seems to be using Lua 5.1.

Comment: Not sure if you know anything about busted but is there a way to make it run 5.3?

Comment: According to the git repository, the standalone program just runs `lua`, whatever version that ends up being. So check how many different `lua`s you have and where they are and why you end up running a different one than busted.